# typescript class with static variable / singleton pattern

Tags: typescript

well i have a question regarding the best way to code this situation:
i have a class where i need to have a static variable in all the project: connection

singleton without name space:

```
class Broker {
  static connection: Connection = undefined;
  static channel: Channel = undefined;
  static urli: string = process.env.RABBIT_URL || 'url';
  static start() {
    return new Promise<Connection>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (Broker.connection || !Broker.urli) {
        const message = !Broker.urli
          ? 'The host of rabbitmq was not found in the environment variables'
          : 'Connection has already been established';
        logger.info(message);
        reject(new Error(message));
      }
      retry<Connection>(() => connect(Broker.urli), 10, 1000)
        .then((conn) => {
          Broker.connection = conn;
          resolve(conn);
        })
        .catch((err) => reject(new Error(err)));
    });
  }
}
export const ConnectionMQ: Connection = Broker.connection;
export const ChannelMQ: Channel = Broker.channel;
export const start = () => {
  return Broker.start();
};
```

**with namespace**

```
//namespace
namespace Broker {
  export type QueuesToAssert = { queue: string; options?: Options.AssertQueue };
  export type ExchangesToAssert = {
    exchange: string;
    type: string;
    options?: Options.AssertExchange;
  };
  export type QueuesToBind = {
    queue: string;
    source: string;
    pattern: string;
    args?: any;
  };
  //static
  class BrokerMain {
    static connection: Connection = undefined;
    static channel: Channel = undefined;
    static urli: string = process.env.RABBIT_URL || 'url';
    static start() {
      return new Promise<Connection>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (BrokerMain.connection || !BrokerMain.urli) {
          const message = !BrokerMain.urli
            ? 'The host of rabbitmq was not found in the environment variables'
            : 'Connection has already been established';
          logger.info(message);
          reject(new Error(message));
        }
        retry<Connection>(() => connect(BrokerMain.urli), 10, 1000)
          .then((conn) => {
            this.connection = conn;
            resolve(conn);
          })
          .catch((err) => reject(new Error(err)));
      });
    }
  }
  export const Connection = BrokerMain.connection;
  export const Channel = BrokerMain.channel;
  export const start = () => {
    return BrokerMain.start();
  };
  export const close = () => {};
}
//usage
const connection = Broker.Connection ? Broker.start() : undefined;
```

I would like to know what is the best / correct option in this situation, or if I could apply another way to the situation.
remembering that I only need 2 unique variables of the class that are unique statics throughout the project.
I have doubts if the singleton is needed in this case or just static already solves

Comment: Neither is appropriate. Use modules. Basically, remove the `namespace Broker {}` wrapper from the namespace example and he happy

Comment: but that way will my connection from the class Broker have a static value throughout the project?

Comment: Of course. But you would do `export let Connection: Connection`; then change `this.connection = conn` to `Connection = conn`. That will fix an existing bug and simply your code

Comment: I edited the code based on that, could you tell me if this is it?

the first code block

Comment: If you can also answer for me to give you +

Comment: That's very close to what I meant but if you look at my last comment, you need to use `export let` for the connection and you need set it when you get the connection in your call back. The problem with your current implementation is that the value never gets updated. `export const ConnectionMQ: Connection = Broker.connection` will always be undefined.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you, if you want to post a reply to vote for you, reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know what is the best / correct option in this situation,

I would definitely recommend the static class methods.

## Reason

`namespace` is a TypeScript only feature and not supported by many tools out of the box e.g. Create React App.

Comment: basarat and in this situation where I said that I only need 2 static variables: connection and channel, that is, just one value in the entire project, would I need to use singleton for this? or just declaring the variable as static would solve it already?

Comment: A `static` is a singleton 